# Develop application to Sync between sql azure database and sql server database

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, microsoft-sync-framework

I am planning to develop .net application to sync data between sql azure database and sql on-premise database and planning to use sync framework. It is easy to develop application and sync data between azure db and sql db, but it need to keep open tcp port 1433 .  SQl azure sync service work without keep opening this port. i need to develop my own application to work as sql azure sync services. Is there any alternative way to do this. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this walkthrough, you basically put a service in the cloud to talk to SQL Azure and have your sync app talk to the service instead of directly connecting to SQL Azure.

The Azure Data Sync Service is structured in a very similar way.

see: [Walkthrough of Windows Azure Sync Service Sample](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1568.walkthrough-of-windows-azure-sync-service-sample.aspx)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the reply. i went through the sample and manage to run the sample. but the problem is sample got client UI project and it initiate the sync. To initiate the sync it need to give azure sync connection string. this code snip fail when port 1433 is not open  SqlSyncScopeProvisioning serverConfig = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(conn);

Comment: then take out the part from the client where it connects directly and move that to the WCF service as well.  what am trying to emphasize is that you can write a WCF service hosted in the cloud that handles the actual connection and synchronization with Azure.